# ¿Como pasar el id de un elemento de php a javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Mi problema es que no puedo cambiar la clase de mis elementos y para evitar recargar la pagina al dar like (es un evento) utilizo attr.
Lo que necesito es saber como puedo pasar el contenido de button id="variable php" es decir que si  en la consulta el resultado de $id es 92 que solo cambie en ese lugar la clase.
A continuación el procedimiento a realizar

1. El usuario da like
2. El boton cambia de color dependiendo de la clase que contenía antes(si fue gusta cambiar a nogusta y si era nogusta cambiar a gusta)
   Ahora el código

   ```
                                   <button value="<?php echo $id; ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" onclick="likear(this.id)" class="fa fa-heart controllers
                                   <?php //this part help to know if the user like this
                                   $count_querya   = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM me_gusta where id_cancion='".$id."' AND user_id='".$user_id."'");
                                       if ($rowa = mysqli_fetch_array($count_querya)) {
                                           $numrowsa = $rowa['numrows'];
                                       } else {
                                           echo mysqli_error($con);
                                       }
                                       if ($numrowsa > 0) {/*there is existents of a song*/
                                       echo " gusta";
                                   }
                                   else{
                                       echo" nogusta";
                                   }
                                   ?>" aria-hidden="true"></button>
   ```

Este es el js

```
function likear(id) {
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'megusta.php',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
    });
    if($('id').val(id).hasClass("gusta")){
        $('id').val(id).attr("class", "fa fa-heart controllers nogusta");
        alert("No gusta cambiado a la cancion "+id);
    }
    else
    {
        $('id').val(id).attr("class", "fa fa-heart controllers gusta");
        alert("Gusta cambiado a la cancion "+id);
    }
}
```

Si no entienden mi explicación o se necesita algo mas háganme saberlo por favor

Comment: Esto lo puedes resolver fácilmente con [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Comment: Me puedes dar un ejemplo porfavor? @A.Cedano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo con [`toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Como podrás ver en el ejemplo, se escuchan los clicks del botón, cambiando entre la clase `meGusta` (color azul) y `noMeGusta` (color rojo). Además, el código permite cambiar el texto de botón según el caso.

```js
$("#btnTest").on("click", function() {
  $btn = $(this);
  $btn.toggleClass('meGusta, noMeGusta');
  /*Para cambiar el texto del botón*/
  let txtYes=`<i class="far fa-thumbs-up">Me Gusta</i>`;
  let txtNot=`<i class="far fa-thumbs-down">No Me Gusta</i>`;
  $btn.html($btn.html() == txtNot ? txtYes : txtNot);
});
```

```css
.meGusta {
  color: blue;
}

.noMeGusta {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnTest" class="meGusta"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up">Me Gusta</i></button>
```

Comment: Gracias, me has ayudado a encontrar la solucion

Comment: @Aldhair me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo unico que tuve que cambiar fue mi js y utilizar la funcion toggleClass

```
function likear(id) {
    console.log(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'megusta.php',
        data: {
            id: id
        },
    });
}
$("button").on("click", function() {
    $btn = $(this);
    $btn.toggleClass('gusta nogusta');
  });
```

Para esta solucion me ayudo @A. Cedano